# Move Uploaded File

Tags: php, html, file-upload, mysqli

I cannot see what I am missing.. I am trying to let users upload a file for a picture post on a social media website, I have already made it so they can choose a profile picture and that works fine, but for some reason this does not work.

```
<div class = "midCol"><?php

    //show post box
    ?><form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class = "box" style = "width:500px;">
        <textarea class = "poster" rows="5" cols="50" id = "area" name = "area" value = "area"
        placeholder = "What's on your mind?"></textarea><br/>
        <input type = "file" id = "picture" name = "picture"/><br/>
        <input type = "Submit" value = "Post" name = "post"/><br/>

    </div>
</form><?php
```

and here is the PHP in the same script:

```
 //submit post
if (isset($_POST['post'])) 
{
    $postContent = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['area']);
    $newPost_query = "INSERT INTO posts (uid, post, uname) VALUES ('$uid', '$postContent', '$uname')";
    $postPicture_query = "UPDATE posts SET picture = postId";

    $postContent_exc = mysqli_query($dbc, $newPost_query);

    //move uploaded file  
    echo $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];
    $pic = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], 'images/posts/' . $pic);
    mysqli_query($dbc, $postPicture_query);

}
```

It's a little messy because I've been changing it left and right and I'll clean it up later, but does anyone see what I am doing wrong??

Comment: It keeps saying "unknown index picture" but I think the picture index is clearly defined in the HTML.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

change it to:

```
<form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

which is required when uploading files.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy!